# Exceed the buffer size?

Tags: c, size, segmentation-fault, buffer

Why is it possible to exceed the buffer size in C up to a certain limit without any error (segmentation fault)?

For example, I was playing with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void function1(char *a) {
   char buf[10];
   strcpy(buf, a);
   printf("End of function1\n");
}

main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
   function1(argv[1]);
   printf("End of main\n");
}
```

I was able to pass as an argument up to 23 characters instead of 10 characters without any errors, but when I use 24 characters I get a segmentation fault.

I know that with the 24th character, I hit the return value. But what about with the previous 13??!!

Answer (score 3):

You did get an error. You exceed a buffer size and nothing terrible happened. Naively, something terrible should happen when you exceed a buffer. What you expected did not happen, the definition of an error.

I'm not trying to be flippant. My point is a serious one -- if you break the rules, you have no idea what will happen. You might get an error. It might appear fine. Something else might happen. In principle, it's unpredictable. It might change from compiler to compiler, operating system to operating system, or even run to run.

Likely what's happened in this case is that `buf` is the last thing on the stack and the space after it isn't used for anything critical. So using some of the space after it is harmless. You may eventually hit a critical structure or hit a page that's not writable, resulting in a fault.

Answer (score 1):

**That's the beauty of undefined behavior**.

- For C, writing outside the array is illegal
- For your operating system, writing at an unmapped address or at an address mapped with the wrong permissions (read-only) is illegal

These ideas of what process is permitted to do don't always match perfectly.

It's perfectly possible for a C program to do something completely brain-damaged that makes the OS say "that's OK with me" because it's indistinguishable from normal operation.

Back to your question, it's likely the first 13 bytes didn't actually bother the OS (they were written in a valid page). Then the next byte probably touched read-only memory or an unmapped address and the OS had a chance to spot the error.